# Handling relations with osm2pgrouting?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I'm trying to create a topology of the public transport in Paris. I use a OSM export, osm2pgrouting with the correspondent mapconfig.xml and Postgis.
Everything works fine, except one thing.

In Paris, there are two kinds of public transportation on railways: the metro and the "RER", which is basically a metro that go further in the suburbs.

I'm am able to import both networks (metro and RER), but I'm not able to connect them properly, i think because on OSM the shared stations are mapped as relations of two nodes (one station for the metro and another one for the RER while it is the same).
One example can be seen there:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2154932

According to :
http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/osm2pgrouting.html
It seems that osm2pgrouting doesn't handle relations.

Is it true that osm2pgrouting doesn't handle relations, or am i over-interpreting ?

If this is true, how can i manage to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right: osm2pgrouting doesn't handle relations at the moment.

If you need support for relations, then someone needed to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think that i will overcome the problem by joining both stations by walking (which is plausible).